# Mysql group by 2 columns using OR

Tags: mysql, database, relation

I have a table of messages representing a conversation:

```
| sender     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| recipient  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| text       | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

Each row has a sender, a recipient, and the text of the message.

I want to run a query that returns all of the conversations and the number of messages in each conversation.

So if the data looks like:

```
1,2,Hello
2,1,Bye
1,3,Hi
```

I want to know that the conversation between 1 and 2 has 2 messages, and the conversation between 1 and 3 has 1 message

So I need to do something like

```
SELECT count(*), SET OF(sender, recipient) from messages group by ( sender OR recipient )
```

But obviously, that doesn't work. Is there anything similar that I can do

Comment: Start here: `SELECT sender user1, recipient user2 FROM my_table UNION SELECT recipient, sender FROM my_table`... or here `SELECT LEAST(sender,recipient) user1, GREATEST(sender,recipient) user2 FROM my_table;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rearrange the pairing by selecting the minimum value of (sender, recipient) first and then the max of (sender, recipient) and grouping by those to get the count for each pair. Try this:

```
SELECT LEAST(sender, recipient) AS firstPerson, GREATEST(sender, recipient) AS secondPerson, COUNT(*) AS numMessages
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LEAST(sender, recipient), GREATEST(sender, recipient);
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle is not loading so this is untested, but I hope this helps out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sender_reciever,COUNT(*) AS message_count
    FROM
    (SELECT (IF(sender>recipient,CONCAT(sender,'_',recipient),CONCAT(recipient,'_',sender))) AS sender_reciever
    FROM
    message_table) T
    GROUP BY sender_reciever
```

Hope this helps